# How to append a `QVariantList` as a self-contained entity to another `QVariantList` in Qt 6?

Tags: qt6

As of Qt 6.0, `QList` has gained a new overloaded method `void QList::append(QList<T> &&value)`. As the documentation says, this ["Moves the items of the value list to the end of this list."](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlist.html#append-4).

So how do I append a `QVariantList` to another `QVariantList` as a self-contained entity?

Prior to Qt 6, the following code

```
QVariantList subList;
subList.append(QVariant(false));
subList.append(QVariant("a string"));

QVariantList containerList;
containerList.append(subList);
```

would result in `containerList` having 1 element, `subList`, which is what I wanted.

As of Qt 6.0, `containerList` ends up with *the contents* of `subList`.

How can I achieve what I had before, in Qt 6?

Comment: I don't have Qt6 installed but... does `containerList.append(QVariant(subList));` work?

Comment: Genius! And so concise. I was headed down a rabbit hole of a global generic function. Want to put this as an answer and take the credit?